# Altium split power plane

Tags: altium, pcb-layers, ground-plane

The layer stack manager has created a power plane for me on which there is a default polygon pour that is the board size : 
[image]

For some reason I can't do a polygon pour on that layer... I would like to have multiple power nets on the power plane, but even if I remove some of the automatically placed polygon, I still can't do a polygon pour.

How can I split my power plane to fit multiple power nets?

Comment: Not 100% sure on this or I'd make it an official answer, but I'm pretty sure "Internal Plane" can only be one net.  If you want split planes, make it a Signal layer instead.  Delete it and click "Add Layer" (Layer == Signal layer)

Comment: @JoelWigton, you are incorrect. Altium can produce split plane layers.

Comment: related (alternate approach): [Using signal layers as power planes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/306169/7036)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To split the plane you have to place lines on the plane. Place >> Line and by pressing tab you can adjust the width of the line.

The line represents places where no copper will exists. You can then double click the regions and assign different nets.

Make sure to assign colours to your nets!

[image]

Comment: see also: [Defining Split Planes](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Internal+Power+and+Split+Planes#InternalPowerandSplitPlanes-DefiningSplitPlanes) in Altium documentation